# Conversions between tf and eigen

Tags: eigen, ros

```c++
Eigen::Affine3f transform_temp = (Affine3f)transforms[i]; 
const Eigen::Matrix3d rotation_part = transform_temp.rotation().cast<double>();
const Eigen::Vector3d translation_part = transform_temp.translation().cast<double>();
tf::Matrix3x3 rot;
tf::Vector3 tra;
tf::matrixEigenToTF(rotation_part, rot);
tf::vectorEigenToTF(translation_part, tra);
tf::Transform temp_transform(rot, tra);

listener->lookupTransform (link, msg_in->header.frame_id, ros::Time(0), tfTransform);

broadcaster->sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(tfTransform * temp_transform.inverse(), ros::Time::now(), link,  "chess_board"));
```

I got the following error. Do not know why, I have `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS tf tf_conversions)` and also `target_link_libraries(${catkin_LIBRARIES})`

```
undefined reference to `tf::matrixEigenToTF(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3> const&, tf::Matrix3x3&)'
```

Comment: I can manually transform this by just copying the tf::matrixEigenToTF() code. But still do not know why calling this function directly does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set up you `CMakeList.txt` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018447/using-eigen-library-in-ros-indigo/31141591#31141591) to properly include Eigen in your project.

Also, you don't need to split the affine transform in the rotation and traslation components (have a look at [Eigen-tf conversion](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf_conversions/html/c++/tf__eigen_8h.html)).

```c++
Eigen::Affine3f transform_eigen = (Affine3f)transforms[i];
tf::Transform transform_tf;
tf::transformEigenToTF(transform_eigen, transform_tf);
```

**EDIT:**
I have suddenly thought about Eigen library and not about what could be actually the problem. Have you added the `tf_conversions` dependency in the `package.xml` file? You have not mentioned it. Also, you have to include the library: `#include <tf_conversions/tf_eigen.h>`

Comment: I have include the file tf_eigen.h, but my package does not need a package.xml. My project just depend on tf. And including tf_eigen.h only make tf::vectorEigenToTF(translation_part, tra) this function pass the compilation but i do not know why tf::matrixEigenToTF gets an error.

Comment: Sorry, I've assumed it was a ROS application. Can you please add the complete CMakeList.txt?