# Link Eigen Library with ROS

Tags: eigen, ros, eigen3

I am a newbie working on ROS Hydro. Most of my codes are based on the Eigen library. I have already installed the library by below codes:

sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev

Now I can find a eigen folder in /opt/ros/hydro/include/Eigen and another folder under /usr/include/eigen3. From what I saw online, this should suggest my installation success.

However, when I build ros package by catkin_make, it reports error that no Eigen/Dense file or directory. I did what this post suggests and it works:

[Using Eigen Library in ROS Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018447/using-eigen-library-in-ros-indigo)

However, this needs me to edit the CmakeLists.txt for every package, to include eigen library and link targets. Is there a more convenient way to set the libraries so that it can work for all my future codes without me touching every CmakeLists for all my packages? Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: Eigen is a header only library and typically there is nothing to link against.
This might be not the best solution but you could export the Eigen path via catkin_package INCLUDE_DIRS

`catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS} ... )`

Comment: Hi @cassinaj ! Thanks for your answer! I think your solution should work, as the post I mentioned above does. BTW, I found another solution, directly moving the Eigen folder to the /usr/include/ directory. In this case, I don't need to modify the CMakeList.txt for every package to include Eigen. I think this should be related to how I set ROS header file including path somewhere. I am not sure. :-)